# Composer updating to 8.9.0beta2 instead of 8.9.0

Tags: composer

I'm currently using the drupal/core-recommended project and I'm having issues updating to 8.9.0.

Some reason composer is updating it to 8.9.0-beta2.

Steps I took to update was go into my composer.json file and changed:
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",

TO
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9",
"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.9",

Then ran composer install

Then it just downloads the beta version instead of the stable version.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried these commands for updating Drupal? Just Core: $>composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies or for Core and Contrib Modules: $>composer update --with-dependencies Personally I don't edit the composer files and then run install. I just run these commands and so far has always worked well.

Comment: I did and I also did:
composer update drupal/recommended --with-dependencies

Comment: I ran into this issue yesterday. Running `composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9  --update-with-all-dependencies` told me I had a conflict with `symfony/polyfill-php72`. I removed the section on this library from `composer.lock`, and was able to properly update to 8.9. Maybe this can help. Back up your system appropriately before running any of these commands.

Comment: Hi Jaypan! Big fan of you by the way haha.

In my composer.lock I have a lot of `symfony/polyfill-php72`. Can you tell me which line to remove?

Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out!! I tried `composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9  --update-with-all-dependencies ` and got a conflict with my guzzle. I updated guzzle and it's working now!! Thank you Jaypan!!

Comment: This and similar dependency conflicts can typically be solved by asking composer to also update symfony packages as described in [Drush blocks update from 8.9.0-beta2 to 8.9.2](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3160252). `composer update drupal/core-recommended symfony/* --with-all-dependencies`